# Initiate JDBC connection once in Spark Streaming job

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, hazelcast

**Environment**

- Spark Streaming job reading from Kafka, micro-batch size 30 seconds (Durations.seconds (30))
- In-memory storage (Hazelcast) having Reference State. This is a non-static State and is updated in real-time by Spark Workers
- Spark Workers connected with Hazelcast

**Current Approach**
 - Using `foreachRDD` to operate on data, and a connection is established for every micro-batch (RDD). This is happening every 30 seconds (Durations.seconds (30)).

```
kafkaStream.foreachRDD (new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
    @Override
    public void call(JavaRDD<String> microBatch) throws Exception {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.addAddress("myHost:5701");    //Define connection
        HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
        //Do processing
   }
}
```

**The Ask**: Would like to open connection once on each Spark Worker(s) (when job is submitted), instead of new connection for each micro-batch. What can be the right way to achieve this?

Comment: There is a very old JIRA on that topic, and it looks like Cloudera and/or Databricks are actively blocking any progress on that matter: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-650

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter: Thanks for the reference. [Static variables](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-572) can be utilized to achieve this too, what's your take on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is well explained here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd

```
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>
    // ConnectionPool is a static, lazily initialized pool of connections
    val connection = ConnectionPool.getConnection()
    partitionOfRecords.foreach(record => connection.send(record))
    ConnectionPool.returnConnection(connection)  // return to the pool for future reuse
  }
}
```

in foreachPartition, the body is executed locally in executors. There you can have static client connection (each worker will be using its own static object, for ex)

I hope it helps.

Thanks,

Comment: What if the micro-batch duration is small `Durations.seconds (10)`? In this case the connection will be reestablished (every 10 secs) on each partition and thus won't solve the problem.

Comment: Not if you use the connectionpool. Each worker will use its own static pool. Playing with de-serializers is not encouraged in the Apache link, and that’s why it falls in this recommendation/pattern

Answer (score 0):

Since Spark serializes the job and distributes it across the Workers, overriding the deserialization method to do *init* tasks (create JDBC connection, initialize variables etc.) helps in Spark Streaming.

**Override Default Deserialization method (Java)**

```
@Override
        private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
                in.defaultReadObject();
        //Init 1
            ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
            clientConfig.addAddress("myHost:5701");    //Define connection
            HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
       //Init 2
            kafkaProducer=new KafkaProducer<>(kafkaProducerProps);
            }
```

Alternatively, one can use the [static hack](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-572) for init tasks until Cloudera/Databricks guys add [init support inherently in Spark](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-650).